# Como evitar que se me desorganice el contenido de una pantalla a otra

Tags: html, css, responsive, mediaqueries

Hola hice un sitio web para mi empresa, este sitio web estará en algunas pantallas de TV de una empresa, los TV tienen dimensiones que desconozco, y cuando hago que funcione en una en la otra se daña. ya la verdad no se que mas hacer, aquí les voy a mostrar las imágenes de como se ve el sitio.

Así se ve en mi laptop.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve en uno de los TV, y así es como se debería ver en todos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve en otro de los TV, como pueden ver esta completamente desconfigurado y la verdad no sé por que.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A todo el que sepa como ayudarme se lo agradecería la verdad estoy algo desesperado ya que no se por qué cambia de TV a otro de una manera tan exagerada.

Este es el código index.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="content"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="google" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="”robots”" content="”noimageindex”">
<title>IQ para todos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" id="www-widgetapi-script" src="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfl7-J3Jh/www-widgetapi.js" async=""></script><script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script><script>


 // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(idVideo) {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          playerVars : {
                listType:'playlist',
                list: 'PLn5lEmVWb0R-YLCFw2FYwptEqkZMRheFN',
                loop: true
            },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == 0) {
          player.loadVideoById({videoId:'qUGY0rWZu4Q'});
          alert("acabo");
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }






var inicio =true;
function startTime() {
  if(inicio) {

    inicio=false;
    realizaProceso();
  }

    var today = new Date();
    var hr = today.getHours();
    var min = today.getMinutes();
    var sec = today.getSeconds();
    ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>a.m.</span>" : "<span>p.m.</span>";
    hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
    hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
    //Add a zero in front of numbers<10
    hr = checkTime(hr);
    min = checkTime(min);
    sec = checkTime(sec);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min  + " " + ap;

    var months = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
    var days = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
    var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
    var curDay = today.getDate();
    var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
    var curYear = today.getFullYear();
    var date = curWeekDay+", "+curDay+" "+curMonth+" "+curYear;
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
    //validarCambios();
    var time = setTimeout(function(){ startTime() }, 500);



}
setInterval("validarCambios();", 10000);
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}




function validarCambios(){
  var parametros = {};
  $.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'controller/index.php',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(request);
         console.log(status);
         console.log(error);
    },
    success:  function (response) {
      if(response.estado['id']>$("body").data("id")) {
       // $("body").attr("data-id", response.estado['id']);
        //realizaProceso();
        location.reload();
      }
    } 
  });
}

function realizaProceso(){
  var parametros = {};
  $.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'controller/index.php',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(request);
         console.log(status);
         console.log(error);
    },
    success:  function (response) {

      /*var randomColor = '#'+ ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6);
      $('#resultado').css({
        'background-color' : randomColor,
      });*/
      $("body").attr("data-year", response.estado['year']);
      $("body").attr("data-month", response.estado['month']);
      $("body").attr("data-day", response.estado['day']);
      $("body").attr("data-hour", response.estado['hour']);
      $("body").attr("data-minute", response.estado['minute']);
      $("body").attr("data-id", response.estado['id']);
      $(".loader").hide();
      $(".carousel-congratulations").html(response.congratulations);
      $(".title-cumple").html(response.titleBirthday);
      $(".carousel-birthdays").html(response.birthdays);
      $(".title-events").html(response.titleEvent);
      $(".carousel-events").html(response.events);
      window.history.pushState("", "", '/iq/pru/');
    }
  });


}




</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()" style="background: #154482;" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="1" data-hour="8" data-minute="20" data-id="651">
<div class="pantalla">
  <div class="mod-left fleft">
    <div class="video fleft">
      <!--<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RQMAn68hvYY?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
      <iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&amp;list=PLn5lEmVWb0R-YLCFw2FYwptEqkZMRheFN&amp;loop=true&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fseadoglabs.com&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="cumeve">
      <div class="cumple fleft">
        <div class="title-cumple"> <span class="fel">Proximo</span> Cumpleaños</div>
        <div class="cont-cumple">

          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-birthdays"><div class="carousel-item active"><div class="container container-happyBirthday"><table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10"><tbody><tr><td><img class="img_picture" src="admin/images/152/152.png"></td><td><h3 class="txt_name">Carlos Andres</h3><h4 class="txt_surname">Ossa Gomez</h4><h5 class="txt_job">Cirujano</h5><h6 class="txt_date">4 de febrero</h6></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
            <!-- AQUI VAN LOS CUMPLEAÑOS-->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="events fleft">
        <div class="title-events">Buenas prácticas</div>
        <div class="content-events" style="padding: 1em;">
          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7100">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-events"><div class="carousel-item"><div class="container container-nextContent"><table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"><tbody><tr><td class="td_dateContents"><h6 style="max-width: 29.6em;line-height: 1.8em;"><b>Escucha y empatiza:</b><br>Intenta comprender lo que siente el paciente, escúchalo… de esta manera se sentirá cómodo y tendrá una mejor experiencia. <br><small>¡Todos hacemos de IQ un mejor lugar!</small></h6></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="carousel-item"><div class="container container-nextContent"><table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"><tbody><tr><td class="td_dateContents"><h6 style="max-width: 29.6em;line-height: 1.8em;"><b>Trato digno a pacientes:</b><br>1. Saluda en forma amable<br>2. Preséntate cuando ingreses al servicio<br>3. Dirígete al paciente por su nombre<br><small>¡Todos hacemos de IQ un mejor lugar!</small>

</h6></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="carousel-item active"><div class="container container-nextContent"><table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"><tbody><tr><td class="td_dateContents"><h6 style="max-width: 29.6em;line-height: 1.8em;"><b>Usa siempre las “palabras mágicas” con tus compañeros</b><br>“por favor”, “permiso” y “gracias”<br><small>¡Todos hacemos de IQ un mejor lugar!</small></h6></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mod-right fleft">
    <div class="logo"><img src="admin/images/logo-iq.png" width="200" height="42"></div>
    <div class="mt30">
      <div class="todos-t fleft">IQ para todos
        <div class="gal">
          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8350">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-congratulations"><div class="carousel-item" style="background: transparent;"><div style="margin-left: 1em;" class="pruebaTmp"><img class="img-l" src="admin/images/felicitaciones/homenajeado4/01.png" style=""></div></div><div class="carousel-item active" style="background: transparent;"><div style="margin-left: 1em;" class="pruebaTmp"><img class="img-l" src="admin/images/felicitaciones/homenajeado5/02.png" style=""></div></div><div class="carousel-item " style="background: transparent;"><div style="margin-left: 1em;" class="pruebaTmp"><img class="img-l" src="admin/images/felicitaciones/homenajeado6/03.png" style=""></div></div><div class="carousel-item " style="background: transparent;"><div style="margin-left: 1em;" class="pruebaTmp"><img class="img-l" src="admin/images/felicitaciones/homenajeado7/04.png" style=""></div></div><div class="carousel-item " style="background: transparent;"><div style="margin-left: 1em;" class="pruebaTmp"><img class="img-l" src="admin/images/felicitaciones/homenajeado8/05.png" style=""></div></div><div class="carousel-item " style="background: transparent;"><div style="margin-left: 1em;" class="pruebaTmp"><img class="img-l" src="admin/images/felicitaciones/homenajeado9/06.png" style=""></div></div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content_hour">
      <div class="fhour">
        <div id="clockdate">
          <div class="clockdate-wrapper">
            <div id="date">Viernes, 1 Febrero 2019</div>
            <div id="clock">08:36 <span>a.m.</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body></html>
```

Este es el main.css

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

html  {
      overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
body {margin:0px; font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; color:#fff;}
.pantalla {height:100vh; width:100%;}

.fel{font-weight:200;}
.fl{font-weight:300;}
.fr{font-weight:400;}
.fsb{font-weight:600;}
.fb{font-weight:700;}

.mt30{margin-top:30px;}
.fleft{float:left;}
.txc{text-align:center;}

.mod-right{background:#154482; width:34%; /*height:100vh;*/height:100%;}
.mod-left{ height:100vh; width:66%; background:#ddd;}
.video iframe{position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 66%;height: 59%;}
.cumeve{width:100%; height:41vh; position:absolute; bottom:0;}
.cumple{ background:#1888c8; height:41vh; width:33%;}
.events{ background:#ff25b0; height:41vh; width:33%;}
.logo{ width:100%; text-align:right; padding:30px 30px 0 0;}
.title-cumple{background:#299fd8; font-size:25px; text-align:center; line-height:64px; }
.title-events{background:#e71a9d; font-size:25px; text-align:center; line-height:64px; }
.iq-todos{background:#ff25b0; margin-top:30px;}
.notas-t{font-size:30px; text-align:center; margin:150px 0 20px;}
.todos-t {font-size:30px;  text-align: center; line-height:50px; width:100%; border-bottom:1px solid #50c1d8; border-top:1px solid #50c1d8;}
.flecha{background:#e71a9d; text-align:right; width:4%}
.des-todos{font-size:20px; padding: 14px 10px; line-height:22px; width:52%; background:#ff25b0; height:91px;}
.desc{font-size:20px; padding:20px; line-height:25px;}
.gal{margin-top:0px;}
.item-t{text-align:center;  padding:15px 0; font-size:25px; background:#1888c8; }
.link{color:#FC0; text-align:center; font-size:25px;}


.container-fluid {padding:0;}
.row{margin:0;}
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto { padding:0; border:1px solid;}
.mod-der{background:#154482; height:100vh;}
.input-small{width: 150px !important;}/* intentar con porcentaje*/
.sin-border{border-color: transparent !important;background:transparent !important;}





.fhour{position:absolute; bottom:20px; right:30px;}
#date{ font-size:20px !important; }
#clock{font-size:38px !important; margin-top:-8px;}
.mod-izq{background:#ddd;}
.video{ background:#09C;}


.container-happyBirthday {
    margin: 15px;
}
.container-nextEvent {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.container-nextContent {
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.td_dateEvent {
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
 }
.td_contentEvent {
    line-height: 15px;
    max-width: 325px;
 }



/*@media tv {
.content{display:-webkit-box; display:-webkit-flex; display:-ms-flexbox; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; width:50vw; height:50vh; overflow:hidden;}
.content-box{display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; width:90%; height:70%;}
.content-box__img{width:100%; height:100%; box-sizing:border-box; margin:0 auto; text-align:left; width:200px;}
.content-box__text{width:100%; height:100%;}
.p_name{font-size:1.2em;}
.img_picture{max-width:max-content;}
}*/




/*CARRUSEL*/
.carousel-item{}
.not-item{width:90%; background:#265ea9; height:auto; margin:0 auto;}
.cum-item {width:90%; height:90%; margin:0 auto;}
.img-cum{border:7px solid #fff; margin-top: 10px;}
.img-l{width:100%;  }
.name{font-size:26px; margin-top:35px; margin-left:10px; line-height:25px; width:50%; }
.cargo{font-size:18px;  margin-left:10px;  margin-top:20px: line-height:25px; }
```

Sitio web
[Pantallas IQ](http://seadoglabs.com/iq/pru/)

Comment: Hay varios temas que debes cuidar, el primero que noto es tu `inicital-scale`, lo tienes con valor 2, debe ser 1. Aplica ese cambio y nos cuentas

Answer (score 2):

Para que tu sitio web sea adaptable a dispositivos móviles debes trabajar en tu CSS con condiciones que hacen referencia a @media con esta etiqueta se trabaja para los diferentes tamaños de pantalla, te dejo unas resoluciones de las más populares.

1350, 1020, 992, 768, 411, 320, 240 y muchas más.

Para que puedas usar una condición en tu CSS te dejo un ejemplo.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {

  .Container
  {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
  }
}

/* La condición indica que solo pantalla (only screen) and (y) que a un tamaño de 992px su width será del 100% y su color de fondo será negro                     .*/
```

Puedes poner las condiciones que requieras según tu necesidad.

Tambien ten presente que en tu main CSS tienes width de 66% que quiere decir esto que sin importar el tamaño de pantalla siempre tendra el 66% de su viewport.

Trata de manejar los container padre o tu main a que siempre abarquen el 100%, asi garatizas que siempre tome toda la pantalla.

Espero sea de utilidad

Comment: Gracias voy a intentar,  y conoces de algun emulador de pantallas de tv que pueda usar en linea o descargar?, lo del 66% ese es el width de iframe para el video

Comment: Entiendo que es del video pero si comprendes lo que te mencione como es 66 si la pantalla es por ejemplo de 2000 el video siempre será de 66% entonces se dañara, lo que te menciono es el RESPONSIVE y la idea de programar para todo tipo de pantalla , no solo para TV, para que puedas ver un emulador esta responsineitor puedes buscarlo en google aunque hay más si buscas.

Comment: Encontre el problema, esos tvs donde se daña el codigo no es smart tv entonces no funcionan un monton de cosas, en cambio en los demas que si son smart si funciona perfecto.

Comment: Podrías intentar instalando un navegador mas estable por ejemplo: Google Chrome, Opera, Firefox, etc. Saludos.

Comment: No se deja instalar nada intentamos y al no ser smart pues no permitio por medio normales